# Hibernate event listeners for JPA callbacks

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-4.x

How can I enable the Hibernate event listeners, that handle JPA callbacks?

Currently I am using using Hibernate 4 with SessionFactory configuration, but JPA callbacks are not running properly, when I persist an object.

Any suggestion are most welcome.

#### Source code

**Temp Entity class:**

```
package com.esp.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.PostLoad;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.esp.aaa.TempVal;

@Entity
@EntityListeners(value=TempVal.class)
@Table(name="TEMP")
public class Temp {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private int roll;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public int getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }
    public void setRoll(int roll) {
        this.roll = roll;
    }
    @PostLoad
    public void load(){
        System.out.println("post load called here");
    }
}
```

**TempVal class:**

```
package com.esp.aaa;

import javax.persistence.PrePersist;

public class TempVal {
    @PrePersist
    public void validate(Object temp){
        System.out.println("Object will persist now");
    }
}
```

**MainClass class:**

```
package com.esp.aaa;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import com.esp.entity.Temp;
import com.esp.utility.HibernateUtils;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HibernateUtils.createSessionFactory();
        Session session=HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Temp temp=new Temp();

        temp.setEmail("abc@gmail.com");
        temp.setName("Lucky");
        temp.setRoll(1112);

        session.save(temp);
        System.out.println("Object persist successfully");

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        HibernateUtils.shutdown();
    }
}
```

**The Hibernate configuration:**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="com.esp.entity.Temp"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

#### Program output

The program output is the following:

```
Hibernate: insert into TEMP (email, name, roll) values (?, ?, ?)
Object persist successfully
```

The expected output would be:

```
Object will persist now
Hibernate: insert into TEMP (email, name, roll) values (?, ?, ?)
Object persist successfully
```

Comment: Please add the program output

Comment: Hibernate: insert into TEMP (email, name, roll) values (?, ?, ?)
Object persist successfully

Comment: And what did you expect?

Comment: Object will persist no 
Hibernate: insert into TEMP (email, name, roll) values (?, ?, ?) 
Object persist successfully

Comment: I am updating your question with these information, next time please feel free to add them, it makes the question much better

Comment: I am not hundred percent sure, but maybe `EntityListener`s are not working with `SessionFactory`, only with `EntityManager`

Comment: ya that's right I already google this and get same ans as yours but I think we can achieve it by configuration but don't know what configuration

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096637/configure-hibernate-4-3-with-sessionfactory-to-use-prepersist) basically asked the same.

So it turns out, that these JPA entity listener annotations are only working when you are using `EntityManager` in Hibernate (which is understandable). So if you want to use these annotations, you should ditch `SessionFactory`, and use the JPA-complaint `EntityManager` or `EntityManagerFactory`.

I also recommend this approach, because if you are trying to use JPA annotations, it is logical to go for a pure JPA solution, without tying yourself to a Hibernate-specific solution - i.e. `SessionFactory`.

Answer (score 7):

Add a file named **org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator** containing a single line

```
org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator
```

in your META-INF/services folder. This will enable JPA lifecycle annotations including @EntityListeners for sessionFactory based configurations.

Comment: I tried that in hibernate 5.1.0 but prepersist hasn't worked still. Any other suggestion about that problem?

Comment: I added the JpaIntegrator() using Hibernate Bootstrapping, as follows:
BootstrapServiceRegistry bootstrapRegistry =
   new BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder()
    .applyIntegrator(new JpaIntegrator())
    .build();
For it to work you need to bootstrap Hibernate manually.
That made it work for Hibernate 5.2.