# @PostRemove doesn't get called

Tags: java, hibernate, callback

I added some callback functions annotated witch @PostUpdate, @PostPersist, @PostRemove in a Listener class added to the entity class with @EntityListeners annotation. When I'm testing the functionality, my callback functions annotated with @PostUpdate and @PostPersist gets called but the function annotated with @PostRemove doesn't get called and the entry gets deleted from the DB. The operations for add, delete and update are made by an EntityManager class.

Anyone have any ideea? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA Callback not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453066/jpa-callback-not-being-called)